# how to read the data from another program in c?

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel, interrupt

A.c

```
extern double interrupttime;
interrupttime = timestamp();
```

//here I am calculating the time stamp and storing it in a interrupttime variable.

B.c
//copying data from kernel space to user space

```
read(struct file *fp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{

copy_to_user(userbuffer, kernelbuffer, count);
// this is the api used to send data from kernel buffer to user buffer
}
```

The above is the kernel code and I want to read the Interrupttime (A.c) from B.c and I want to copy the interrupt time in B.c program api and later send it to the user space. So someone please help me to read the data from B.c program ??

Comment: You can use debugfs (for example) to pass data between kernel and user spaces.

Comment: you can use proc fs or sysfs to pass the information

Comment: but I want to transfer the interrupttime calculated in A.c from B.c(procfs api) program. how to do that ??  A.c is a kernel code and B.c is an procfs api.